# Google Apps Script - submitButton UI elements - Unexpected Error Occurred

Tags: google-apps-script

I just started using gApps scripts and I have run into two problems with my code (below) while trying to set up my UI to disable the submit button while a task is processing.

1. When trying to load the script I occasionally get the following error: "Error Encountered: Unexpected Error Occurred".  This error is not consistent in that all I need to do is refresh the script and then it will load for me.  It really bothers me that it sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't, when I haven't changed the code at all.
2. When the 3rd last line `//button_submit.setEnabled(true);` is un-commented the error occurs every time I try to load the script.

I while trying to figure out what was wrong I noticed that getElementById() didn't seem to be assigning the correct UI type to the submit button.  I'm unsure if this is the cause of the problem, but I suspect it isn't as I saw the same behavior in the test script I made to see if I could replicate the issue from a simpler foundation.

I'd appreciate any feedback you might have as to what's causing this issue.

Thanks

Chris B-P

```
Logging output

populate_assign_list spinner.getId():spinner
populate_assign_list spinner.getType():Image
populate_assign_list button_submit.getId():button_submit
populate_assign_list button_submit.getType():Generic
doGet button_submit.getId():spinner
doGet button_submit.getType():Image
doGet button_submit.getId():button_submit
doGet button_submit.getType():SubmitButton
```

.

```
//define global script property variables
var prop_home_folder_id;       //String - Contains the home folder's ID string
var prop_subject_folder_names; //Array of Strings - Listing of folder names
var prop_subject_folder_ids;   //Array of Strings - Listing of folder IDs associated with folder names
var prop_submisison_ss_ids;    //Array of Strings - Losting of sumission spreadsheet IDs
var prop_allow_anon_submit;    //Flag - Allow manual entry of email address (ie. non domain access) Default to FALSE

function save_script_prop_(home_folder_id, subject_folder_names, subject_folder_ids, submisison_ss_ids, allow_anon_submit) {
  //array values must be sent to this function as comma separated strings ie   <array>.join(',')
  if (home_folder_id != null) ScriptProperties.setProperty("home_folder_id", home_folder_id);
  if (subject_folder_names != null) ScriptProperties.setProperty("subject_folder_names", subject_folder_names);
  if (subject_folder_ids != null) ScriptProperties.setProperty("subject_folder_ids", subject_folder_ids);
  if (submisison_ss_ids != null) ScriptProperties.setProperty("submisison_ss_ids", submisison_ss_ids);
  if (allow_anon_submit != null) ScriptProperties.setProperty("allow_anon_submit", allow_anon_submit);
}

function load_script_prop_() {
  /*
  prop_home_folder_id = ScriptProperties.getProperty("home_folder_id");
  prop_subject_folder_names = ScriptProperties.getProperty("subject_folder_names").split(",");
  prop_subject_folder_ids = ScriptProperties.getProperty("subject_folder_ids").split(",");
  prop_submisison_ss_ids = ScriptProperties.getProperty("submisison_ss_ids").split(",");
  prop_allow_anon_submit = ScriptProperties.getProperty("allow_anon_submit");
  //*/
  prop_home_folder_id = "";
  prop_subject_folder_names = ["1","2","3"];
  prop_subject_folder_ids = ["1","2","3"];
  prop_submisison_ss_ids = ["a","b","c"];
  prop_allow_anon_submit = false;
}




function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   app.add(app.createLabel("Form submitted"));
   return app;
}

function doGet() {
  load_script_prop_();
  var testing_message = "";

  //create ui app and panels
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Assignment Submission");
  var v_panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  v_panel.setSpacing(20);
  var layout_grid = app.createGrid(5,2);
  var form_panel = app.createFormPanel();
  var tab_panel_upload = app.createTabPanel().setId("tab_panel_upload");
  var v_panel_upload_file = app.createVerticalPanel().setTag(0); //Tag refrenced the number of upload elements currently in the tab
  var v_panel_upload_gdoc = app.createVerticalPanel().setTag(0); //Tag refrenced the number of gdoc elements currently in the tab


  //create menu objects
  var spinner = app.createImage("http://www.worldmsday.org/1000-faces/images/whatami/spinner.gif").setVisible(false).setId("spinner");
  var datebox_submission = app.createDateBox().setId("submission_datebox").setValue(new Date()).setEnabled(false);
  var textbox_user = app.createTextBox().setId("textbox_user").setName("textbox_user").setValue(Session.getUser().getEmail()).setEnabled(false);

  var lb_subject_folder = app.createListBox().setId("lb_subject_folder").setName("lb_subject_folder");
  lb_subject_folder.setVisibleItemCount(1);
  for (var i in prop_subject_folder_names) lb_subject_folder.addItem(prop_subject_folder_names[i], i);
  lb_subject_folder.setSelectedIndex(0);

  var lb_assign_list = app.createListBox().setId("lb_assign_list").setName("lb_assign_list");
  lb_assign_list.setVisibleItemCount(1);
  populate_assign_list();
  lb_assign_list.setSelectedIndex(0);

  var button_submit = app.createSubmitButton("Submit").setId("button_submit");
  Logger.log("doGet button_submit.getId():"+spinner.getId());
  Logger.log("doGet button_submit.getType():"+spinner.getType());
  Logger.log("doGet button_submit.getId():"+button_submit.getId());
  Logger.log("doGet button_submit.getType():"+button_submit.getType());


  //button_submit.setEnabled(false);
  //button_submit.setEnabled(true);

  var upload_1 = app.createFileUpload().setName("upload_1");
  var gdoc_1 = app.createLabel("Not Yet Implemented");




  //create menu handlers
  var handler_lb_subject_folder_spinner = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(spinner).setVisible(true);
  handler_lb_subject_folder_spinner.forTargets([lb_assign_list, tab_panel_upload]).setVisible(false);
  handler_lb_subject_folder_spinner.forTargets(button_submit).setEnabled(false);

  var handler_lb_subject_folder = app.createServerHandler("populate_assign_list").addCallbackElement(v_panel);
  lb_subject_folder.addChangeHandler(handler_lb_subject_folder_spinner);
  lb_subject_folder.addChangeHandler(handler_lb_subject_folder);
  //need to add an onchange handler for subject folder listbox which updates the assignment selection listbox.


  //add ui objects to ui
  layout_grid.setText(0,0, "Date: ");
  layout_grid.setWidget(0, 1, datebox_submission);
  layout_grid.setText(1,0, "Name: ");
  //layout_grid.setWidget(1, 1, "");  
  layout_grid.setText(2,0, "Email Address: ");
  layout_grid.setWidget(2, 1, textbox_user);
  layout_grid.setText(3,0, "Course: ");
  layout_grid.setWidget(3, 1, lb_subject_folder);
  layout_grid.setText(4,0, "Assignment: ");
  layout_grid.setWidget(4, 1, lb_assign_list);
  v_panel.add(layout_grid);

  v_panel.add(spinner);

  v_panel_upload_file.add(upload_1);
  tab_panel_upload.add(v_panel_upload_file, "Upload File");

  v_panel_upload_file.add(gdoc_1);
  tab_panel_upload.add(v_panel_upload_gdoc, "Share gDoc");
  tab_panel_upload.selectTab(0);
  v_panel.add(tab_panel_upload);


  v_panel.add(button_submit);

  form_panel.add(v_panel);
  app.add(form_panel);



  var testing_label = app.createLabel("No Test Output").setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center");
  if (testing_message != "") debug_label.setText(testing_label);
  app.add(testing_label);

  return(app);
 }

function populate_assign_list(e) {
  load_script_prop_();

  if (e == null) subject_id=0;
    else subject_id = e.parameter.lb_subject_folder;

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var lb_assign_list = app.getElementById("lb_assign_list");
  lb_assign_list.clear();

  var assign_list = ["x","y","z" ];

  for (var i = 1; i < assign_list.length; i++) {
    lb_assign_list.addItem(assign_list[i]  );
  }


  lb_assign_list.setVisible(true);
  var spinner = app.getElementById("spinner").setVisible(false);
  Logger.log("populate_assign_list spinner.getId():" + spinner.getId());
  Logger.log("populate_assign_list spinner.getType():" + spinner.getType());
  app.getElementById("tab_panel_upload").setVisible(true);

  var button_submit = app.getElementById("button_submit");
  Logger.log("populate_assign_list button_submit.getId():"+button_submit.getId());
  Logger.log("populate_assign_list button_submit.getType():"+button_submit.getType());
  //button_submit.setEnabled(true);

  return app; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide and conquer -

I have had this error a few times, the only way I could track down
 the cause was "Divide and conquer".

...

Causes I know of ...

A) same object ID used for different types of object, even if the old object has been removed.

B) invalid color value

C) Creating the app object twice with createApplication

The error looks to be a kind of catch all error message. 
It also looks to be a client side error, so not sure logging will help.

Comment: I suspected as much.  I was hoping I was overlooking something wrong/stupid and it'd be an easy fix.